# How to add dockerfile to https://hub.docker.com?

Tags: dockerfile, dockerhub

After the successful pushing of a docker image, I can see some repo has "Dockerfile" section while some have not.

[image: dockerfile]

> How to add "Dockerfile" to own repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to set up an automated build of a code repository. [See the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) to learn how to set up automated builds.

The basic steps are:

1. Link a code repository (e.g., GitHub repository) to DockerHub
2. DockerHub will build a Docker image for that repository using the `Dockerfile` in the repository. You can configure the location of this file and the image tags.
3. Once this is set up and your first image is built, you should see the `Dockerfile` listed on DockerHub.

Comment: Does it need to have same username? (Github & Dockerhub)

Comment: EDIT: No, It don't.